# Meaning of "I may have thrown in a little thing here or there...''

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I read this line in **Merriam Webster word of the day**-fastidious

> "I may have thrown in a little thing here
>    or there, but I'm pretty fastidious about 
>   sticking to the script if I like it…." 
>                  —
>   Michael Shannon, Screen International, 
>   21 Nov. 2016

Can someone please tell me what that line meant in the context. I'd like to know only the meaning of ***I may have thrown in a little thing here
 or there.***

Comment: here or there|here and there = in a few places  (similar to **now and then**)

Comment: There are a lot of "distancing" phrases in this statement. The phrases "may have", "thrown in", "little thing", and "here or there" all have a distancing effect, and the speaker uses all four of them consecutively.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a screenplay (a script), there is dialogue. Generally, actors need to memorize the lines and speak them as written.

Sometimes, directors will tolerate some differences with the script when the actors say the lines in a slightly different way, when they do not "stick to" the script (follow it exactly).

To throw in a little thing here and there means: to put in small changes of your own to the lines as written. Here and there refers to here and there [in the script].

The speaker is saying that he may have added a few words or expressions of this own. This can make it better if the actor is a great actor (a Meryl Streep, for instance) or it may just annoy  the director.

Comment: In a word: Improvising

Comment: Or [ad libbing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ad%E2%80%93lib)

Comment: @DoritoStyle No, ad libbing and improvising are very different. To improvise is when you don't know your lines ***at all*** and just make them up; also, it is a style of comedy; Ad libbing is to get up in public and speak without any preparation and can be for acting. That said: neither mean *throwing a little  something in*, which implies actually know  your lines but add to them in some way.

Comment: Thats a bit of a pedantic distinction, especially in a more general sense

Comment: @DoritoStyle My explanation is not pedantic at all; It is very semantically specific.

Comment: @Lambie your definitions of ad libbing and improvising are limited and do not reflect either common usage or dictionary definitions.

Comment: @barbecue - This is a tough one. I’ve just looked at several sites where people weigh in on the similarities & differences between these two terms. Though dictionaries may treat them as just about interchangeable, it seems like some in the performing arts like to make a distinction. See, e.g., the end of [this online discussion](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/improvise-v-ad-lib.2495051/), or watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRdIztHLxl4), where an actor explains that “an ad-lib is not an improv.” And a book on acting says [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t6ul.png).

Comment: @barbecue Around where I live, we say: Whatevah. In any event, improvise and adl lib are not "throw in a little something here and there". They are about acting a part or speaking  ***completely off the top of one's head***. And by the way, I've done quite a bit of theater. So, they can mean the same but there can be differences. You might improvise remarks as an invited speaker. You probably would not refer to that as "ad libbing". Finally, it is not "performing arts". It's theater and film. Mime is a performing art, it doesn't involved speech.

Comment: "He improvised those remarks" or "She didn't know the recipe by heart, so she improvised" [non-theater or acting context]. One would most likely not say: "He ad libbed those remarks". An improvisation is to take a situation and just act it (provide lines and movement) without pre-written lines/script, on your own or with other actors. What's My Line is all improv: brilliant improv.  Actors learn to improvise/practice improvisation in acting school. Ad libbing is not something  you learn in acting school.

Comment: @Lambie - I specifically said “performing arts” because musicians also have specific meanings for ad libbing and improvisation – it’s not just theater and film people who may throw a little something in here and there.

Comment: @J. R. Yes, jazz. Not sure I would call it, strictly speaking, a performing art. Or Jimi Hendrix's rock riffs. Classical music is strictly speaking a performing art and they don't improvise.

Comment: *shrugs*. Suit yourself. But... _Considering the history of classical music and the evolution of the guitar, it’s perhaps surprising that improvisation does not play a larger role. Improvisation was a commonplace in early classical music. Musicians from the Renaissance, Baroque, Classical, and Romantic periods improvised ornaments such as trills, mordents, appoggiatura, and other embellishments; composers the likes of Bach, Mozart and others extemporized whole forms including the ricercar, fugue, and variations._ [(Source)](https://www.johnwwarren.com/blog/improvisation-and-classical-guitar)

Comment: @Lambie I have indeed heard people describe informal activities as ad-libbing. The fact that your theater folks don't use it that way is irrelevant. "That bass is frightful" takes on different connotations depending on whether I'm back stage at a rock concert, in the stalls at a Mozart concerto, or hanging around the parking lot of a Circle K on Saturday evening.  
Also, claiming that classical music doesn't involve improvisation pretty much blows your credibility.

Comment: @barbecue describe informal activities as ad libbing?? Ad libbing has nothing to do with the formality or informality of activities. And naysaying the way you are doing is not helpful. "That bass is frightful" is indeed ambiguous but is not related to "ad libbing". Don't forget the fish!! Naysaying and saying something is irrelevant without explaining it is not helpful.

Comment: @lambie I used **Informal** in the sense of unplanned, casual, and lacking in organization or structure, not in the sense of T-shirts versus tuxedos. I don't often misuse words, and I didn't in this case, but since my exact word choice seems to be causing you a problem, where you see the word "informal" you can substitute the following: **not carefully planned and executed, lacking in deliberate structure, casual in nature.**

Comment: @Lambie You call me a naysayer because I disagree with your statement. You make a claim which I dispute. You said: 'One would most likely not say: "He ad libbed those remarks."' I maintain that one absolutely can and does use that wording. In fact, it's commonplace, and widely used.

Comment: @barbecue Say and maintain anything you like. I said: "You might improvise remarks as an invited speaker. You ***probably would not refer to that*** as "ad libbing"***. I did not make a claim about spoken language. I was talking about referring to a speech situation. There  is a difference between referring to an activity and referring to what a person actually says. For the level of the OP's question, my answer was well within standard parameters and  you seem hell bent on wanting to water it down and sound way off the mark.

Comment: @Lambie you've managed to muddy the waters with your distracting tangential claims so thoroughly that it's completely impossible to respond to all of your many different claims in less than an essay. I made a single, simple claim, and you repeatedly focus on minutiae rather than respond to that claim. Ad-libbing can be and is used in a way you claim it is not. Since you prefer to pick apart my word choices rather than address the only point I've ever made, I'm done.

Answer (score 5):

The generic form of this idiomatic expression is "to throw in (a little) something", meaning, "to add your own personal changes".  Example:

> The recipe was pretty dull so I *threw in a little something* to spice it up.

As with many other idiomatic expressions you can "throw in a little something" to personalize it:

> I may have thrown in a little thing here or there
>
> I tossed in a little thing I came up with.

Or, as an (already outdated) slang expression:

> [I thought I'd add a little sum-sum on the end.](https://youtu.be/WRcVvyLabOU?t=66)